# Loop through div with unique class, find div and append to parent div

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="camera_wrap">
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-1.jpg" class="test"></div>
  <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">a</div>
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-2.jpg" class="test"></div>
  <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">b</div>
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-3.jpg" class="test"></div>
  <div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">c</div>
</div>
```

I have to move the divs with the class="camera_caption" into the parent div like this:

```
<div id="camera_wrap">
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-1.jpg" class="test"><div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">a</div></div>
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-2.jpg" class="test"><div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">b</div></div>
  <div data-src="Slider-Image-3.jpg" class="test"><div class="camera_caption fadeFromBottom">c</div></div>
</div>
```

How can i do this?

Mario

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop. jQuery provides `each`:

```
$('.camera_caption').each(function(){
    var o=$(this);
    o.appendTo(o.prev());
});
```

(`prev` gets the preceding element, so this will add each `camera_caption` div to the div immediately before it)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".camera_caption").each(function(){
    $(this).prev('.test').append($(this));       
});
```

After, edit I removed line that was causing element to be removed completely. Though this works, I still suggest to do this when markup is being generated if you want such html structure.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2fEQw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".camera_caption").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).prev().html(element);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCTr5/1/

Oh, and those are sibling nodes not parent nodes ;)

Answer (score 0):

make it like this:

```
$('[data-src^="Slider-Image"]').each(function () {
    $(this).append($(this).next('.camera_caption').html());
});
$('[data-src^="Slider-Image"]').siblings('.camera_caption').remove();
```

First loop through the `data-src="Slider-Image"` with `.each()` function and just put the next div's `.html()` through `.append()` and then outside of the loop find the siblings of it and remove it.

#### [FIND IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NamxS/)